# WSL: Issues with .env File Parsing for Environment Variables with Special Characters

Tags: python, environment-variables, token, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm facing an issue with parsing environment variables from a .env file in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). It seems that when I run Python code outside of debug mode, the interpreter does not recognize variables with quotes as strings. This causes the = character within the variable value to split the variable incorrectly.

Here's an example of my .env file (test.env):

```
TOKEN="abc=def"
```

I tried using the python-dotenv package to load the variables, and here's my Python code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv(dotenv_path='test.env')

token = os.getenv('TOKEN')
print(token)
```

I tried using pydantic-setting as well, here's my code:

main.py

```
from env import EnvVarsConfig

settings = EnvVarsConfig()
token = settings.TOKEN
print(token)
```

env.py

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings

class EnvVarsConfig(BaseSettings):

     TOKEN: str

     class config:

          env_file = '.env'
          case_sensitive = True
```

When I run this code in WSL normally, the output is abc, which indicates that the = sign is being treated as a separator. However, when I run the same code in debug mode, the output is abc=def, which is the correct value.

I've tried different approaches, such as not using quotes (TOKEN=abc=def), escaping the = character (TOKEN="abc=def"), and manually loading the .env file, but none of them seem to work outside of debug mode.

Is there a way to ensure that the Python interpreter treats variables with quotes as strings when parsing a .env file in WSL, similar to how it behaves when I am running in debug mode? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

*edit:*

I am using poetry to manage my environment, and using a poetry shell as interpretor.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I ran the dotenv part without using debug mode in WSL and the output was `abc=def`.

Comment: Maybe using poetry you may be able to reproduce the same output? I have edited the question adding this information.

Comment: No, you're looking in the wrong direction. Its the dotenv package's code that handles parsing the env file, I don't see what poetry has to do with that. One potential issue you should check is that the `TOKEN` environment variable might **already** be set by something else before `load_dotenv` is run.

Comment: Well, it is so weird, even when I change my .env and run the project, if I run it as debug, the change is there, and if I run it normally, it stays as it was before. I have to close vscode and open it again with "code ." on wsl terminal.

Comment: Then as I mentioned that environment variable is already set before you ran `load_dotenv`. It doesn't overwrite existing variables unless specified. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63589351/environment-variables-not-updating

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, help me to undertand what happened here. I was restarting vscode to update my variable, and it was updating, because I was changing the content before the "=". But somehow, just by adding this override parameter like this load_dotenv(override = True), the interpretor stop splitting the string. Okay, it is overriding now, but why does this work, and it wasn't working before?

Comment: As I mentioned you **already** have that environment variable set. You can see that by running `print(os.getenv('TOKEN'))` **before** your call to `load_dotenv`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256894/discussion-between-davi-bogo-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).